# How do I change the UIView programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have created View A and View B. My window has View A displayed on the screen. I also have a UIButton on View A. I want to switch from View A to View B when I click on the Button. I am not using any UIViewController. Is it possible to switch the views without using controller? 
I am calling buttonAction method on TOUCHUPINSIDE

The problem is that it doesn't do anything when I say

[ViewA removeFromSuperView];

What should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If viewB is not in the view hierarchy:

```
[[viewA superview] addSubview:viewB];
```

If viewB is in the view hierarchy:

```
[[viewA superview] bringSubviewToFront:viewB];
```

Once viewB is in the view hierarchy, then remove viewA:

[viewA removeFromSuperview];